# Is there a way to pull out AWS EC2 bill usage ? Does amazon provide us with any REST API to get this data

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, billing

We would like to manage AWS users billing cycles. Does AWS provide an API to get this informtation programmatically ?

Comment: Duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157080/aws-billing-information-using-aws-java-api

Comment: @droidlabour ... the other post is a duplicate of this post .. I had asked this  in 2012 .. the other post was in 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Cloudwatch, you can get Billing Alerts. You will be notified by SNS when your billing gets above your defined limits. Read more about this in [this blog post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/monitor-estimated-costs-using-amazon-cloudwatch-billing-metrics-and-alarms.html) or in the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html). Of course you can also use the [CloudWatch API](http://aws.amazon.com/de/documentation/cloudwatch/) to get custom reports using this data.