# aws billing information using aws java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get the billing information from aws for ec2 instances, s3 buckets and ebs volumes using java api. I want to create api that gives specific entity wise hourly billing reports. Is there any java api for getting the same? I couldn't find the same in aws java sdk api documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no APIs to get AWS billing information. Instead what you can do is:

1. Turn on the detailed billing report (from dashboard)
2. Configure what kind of billing reports you want
3. AWS will start pushing billing info as CSV files to a (pre)configured bucket several times an hour
4. Use REST API or S3 Java API to get the information from the bucket when needed.

For more information: [See here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html)

Comment: I'm actually looking for any API that gives me usage with pricing. Is there any aws api that will provide me usage for EC2 instances, EBS volumes and S3 storage ?

Comment: Try getCostAndUsage in the Java SDK : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html (com.amazonaws.services.costexplorer.AWSCostExplorerClient)

Answer (score 6):

In Addition to @helloV answer, if you want to view your AWS Billings across  days/hours or even minutes. You can use [aws-elk-billing](https://github.com/PriceBoardIn/aws-elk-billing) tool. Currently the pull request is awaiting to be merged with [the main repository](https://github.com/ProTip/aws-elk-billing/pull/3). It uses ELK Stack to visualise the AWS Cost and Usage Report

(Although it might still work with AWS Detailed billing report which contains some extra columns along with all the columns from AWS Cost and Usage Report).

Here's a full screenshot of the Kibana Dashboard.

[image: AWS Billing Kibana Dashboard]

Answer (score 5):

Updating the answer as it is no longer the correct one. AWS has released the CostExplorer API for the Java SDK. You can find the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html

```
public GetCostAndUsageResult getCostAndUsage(GetCostAndUsageRequest request)
```

> Retrieves cost and usage metrics for your account. You can
>   specify which cost and usage-related metric, such as BlendedCosts or
>   UsageQuantity, that you want the request to return. You can also
>   filter and group your data by various dimensions, such as SERVICE or
>   AZ, in a specific time range. For a complete list of valid dimensions,
>   see the GetDimensionValues operation. Master accounts in an
>   organization in AWS Organizations have access to all member accounts.

Comment: @bagui FYI if you're still looking for it and want to update your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can get Cost and Usage Data using AWS Java SDK. Here is a functional sample.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;

import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

import com.amazonaws.services.costexplorer.AWSCostExplorer;

import com.amazonaws.services.costexplorer.AWSCostExplorerClientBuilder;

import com.amazonaws.services.costexplorer.model.DateInterval;

import com.amazonaws.services.costexplorer.model.GetCostAndUsageRequest;

import com.amazonaws.services.costexplorer.model.GetCostAndUsageResult;

public class AwsCostExplorer {

    private static AWSCostExplorer awsCostExplorerClient;

    public static void main(String arg[]){

AWSCostExplorerClientBuilder builder =AWSCostExplorerClientBuilder.standard();

        awsCostExplorerClient = builder.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("profile-name").getCredentials()))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();

        GetCostAndUsageRequest request = new GetCostAndUsageRequest()
                .withTimePeriod(new DateInterval().withStart("2018-07-01").withEnd("2018-07-25"))
                .withGranularity("DAILY")
                .withMetrics("BlendedCost");

        GetCostAndUsageResult result = awsCostExplorerClient.getCostAndUsage(request);

        result.getResultsByTime().forEach(resultByTime -> {
            System.out.println(resultByTime.toString());
        });

        awsCostExplorerClient.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@bagui

As per AWS official documentation, there is no as such API feature available to get actual billing usages data. Instead you can get the expected billing data as:

To get started, all you need to do is to provide an Amazon S3 bucket for your billing data, give the AWS Billing system permission to write to it, and visit the Billing Preferences page to enable programmatic access:

Once you have done this, we will generate an Estimated bill several times per day and store it in the bucket, where you can download and process it as desired. We will also generate a Final bill at the conclusion of each billing period.

Billing Reports are generated as CSV files and include plenty of details:

Here is a list of the fields (read the documentation for more information):

- Invoice ID
- Payer Account Name and ID
- Linked Account Name and ID (for Consolidated Billing)
- Record Type
- Record ID
- Billing Period Start and End Dates
- Invoice Date
- Taxation Address
- Payer Purchase Order Number
- Product Code
- Product Name
- Seller of Record
- Usage Type
- Operation
- Rate ID
- Item Description
- Usage Start and Usage End Date and Time
- Usage Quantity
- Blended Rate (for Consolidated Billing)
- Currency Code
- Cost Before Tax
- Credits
- Tax Amount
- Tax Type
- Total Cost

Referred AWS documentation:
[Programmatic Access to AWS Billing Data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-programmatic-access-to-aws-billing-data/)

Thanks