# List all AWS billable resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to list all the billable resources (basically EC2,EBS,RDS) in an AWS account.Is there any aws-cli command or script available to do so.

I have the aws account root access.

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157080/aws-billing-information-using-aws-java-sdk

Comment: I'm not sure the requester is asking about billing details. It sounds like he just wants a list of all the resources created in an account.

Comment: **See Also**: [Is there a way to list all resources in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44391817/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to retrieve billing details for AWS resources via AWS CLI directly.

What you can do is store billing reports on S3 and then you can programmatically read and analyze those reports that are generated in CSV format (Billing -> Preferences).

Reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports.html#turnonreports