# Amazon EC2 Billing APIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am wondering if it is possible to see billing information through the Amazon SDK/APIs. Specifically, I want to see how much EC2 instances are costing the account. Is it feasible to have it break down by user if it is an IAM account, or breakdown by account if you are using consolidated billing?

I have seen ways of doing this by either creating an S3 bucket to have billing info dumped into, or using CloudWatch APIs which require the user to pay. Is there an easier way to get EC2 billing information through just API calls or the SDK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aws billing information using aws java sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157080/aws-billing-information-using-aws-java-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Billing information can be provided as records in an Amazon S3 bucket. You can then analyze the content of those files to obtain the information you list.

It is not possible to obtain the billing records themselves via an API call.

See: [Cost and Usage Report](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html)

(The older *Detailed Billing Report* is scheduled to be retired.)